# Can any Language that is generated LL1 Grammar is regular.?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language

I have a question is every language generated by LL(1) grammar is regular? I know that every regular language can be generated by LL(1) grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The $LL(1)$ grammar $S \to a S b \mid c$ generates $\{a^n c b^n \colon n \ge 0\}$, which is (rather trivially) non-regular.